# How come my Python program does not work to do a word count that excludes stopwords?

Tags: python, cpu-word

This is my first time programming. 
This is the code i wrote. I'm doing this on a text file to count the content words, but not the stopwords, like "the", or "a."
whenever i print the progran i wrote it counts all the words, including the stopwords.
here is my program i wrote.

```
 from collections import Counter


with open("words.py") as input_file:
   count = Counter(word for line in input_file
                     for word in line.split())

stop_words = frozenset(['the', 'a', 'is'])
def mostCommonWords(concordanceList):
    finalCount = Counter()
    for line in concordanceList:
        words = [w for w in line.split(" ") if w not in stop_words]
        finalCount.update(words)  # update final count using the words list
    return finalCount
print(count.most_common(10))
```

Comment: You're not calling your function `mostCommonWords`. How do you intend to call it?

Comment: So where do i have to call it mostCommonWords. ?

Answer (score 0):

You *define* the `mostCommonWords` function, but you never *call* it.

The program prints `count.most_common(10)`, which is the whole file, including stop words.

Comment: what do you mean? i change the print?